# firebase swift queries in queries performance

Tags: swift, performance, firebase, observers, subquery

I am new to Firebase and relatively new to Swift.

I have firebase set up as below. I have users, followers and blocked users. I take care of the followers in the UITableViewCell class.
I am wondering, before I go any further: how does performance get affected  by putting observers in observers in queries in queries. (Hope these are the correct terms) . Is below the right way to go about it?(the most efficient way). It works, but also seems to stutter a bit. I appreciate any feedback.

```
{
  "BlockedByUsers" : {
    "ba1eb554-9a81-4a74-bfd9-484a32eee13d" : {
    "97fee08f-19b2-4eb5-9eab-4b1985c22595" : true
    }
  },
 "Dates" : {
    "1457635040" : {
    "97fee08f-19b2-4eb5-9eab-4b1985c22595" : true
    },
  },
 "Locations" : {
    "97fee08f-19b2-4eb5-9eab-4b1985c22595" : {
    ".priority" : "u14dkwm41h",
    "g" : "u14dkwm41h",
    "l" : [ 51.05521018175982, 3.720297470654139 ]
    },
  },
 "Users" : {
   "97fee08f-19b2-4eb5-9eab-4b1985c22595" : {
   "blockedUsers" : {
      "ba1eb554-9a81-4a74-bfd9-484a32eee13d" : true
    },
   "following" : {
     "51879163-8b35-452b-9872-a8cb4c84a6ce" : true,
    },
   "fullname" : "",
   "dates" : 1457635040,
   "location" : "",
  },
 }
}
```

my Swift code with the multiple queries I'm worried about:

```
var usersRef: Firebase!
var userFollowingRef: Firebase!
var blockedByUsersRef: Firebase!
var datesRef: Firebase!
var geofireEndRef: Firebase!

var geoFireEnd: GeoFire? {

    return GeoFire(firebaseRef: geofireEndRef)
}

var dateRangeStart = Int()
var dateRangeEnd = Int()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    usersRef = DataService.ds.REF_USERS
    userFollowingRef = DataService.ds.REF_CURRENTUSER_FOLLOWING
    blockedByUsersRef = DataService.ds.REF_BLOCKED_BY_USERS
    datesRef = DataService.ds.REF_DATES
    geofireEndRef = DataService.ds.REF_GEOFIREREF_END
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if userdefaultsUid != nil
    {
        geoFireEnd!.getLocationForKey(userID, withCallback: { (location, error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("An error occurred getting the location for \(self.userID) : \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else if (location != nil)
            {
                self.updateUsersWithlocation(location)

            } else
            {
                print("GeoFire does not contain a location for \(self.userID)")

                self.updateUsersWithoutLocation()
            }
        })
    }
}

func updateUsersWithlocation(location: CLLocation)
{
    var allKeys = [String]()

    let locationQuery = self.geoFireEnd!.queryAtLocation(location, withRadius: 100.0)

    locationQuery.observeEventType(GFEventType.init(0), withBlock: {(key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

        allKeys.append(key)

        self.datesRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryStartingAtValue(String(self.dateRangeStart)).queryEndingAtValue(String(self.dateRangeEnd)).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            snapshot in

            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.newKeys.removeAll()
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            for datesKey in snapshot.children
            {
                self.usersRef.childByAppendingPath(datesKey.key!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                    if let key = datesKey.key where key != self.userID
                    {
                        if  allKeys.contains(key!) {

                            let newuser = FBUser(userKey: key!, dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject])

                            self.blockedByUsersRef.childByAppendingPath(key).childByAppendingPath(self.userID).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in

                                if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull
                                {
                                    // we have not blocked  this one
                                    self.blockedByUsersRef.childByAppendingPath(self.userID).childByAppendingPath(key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                                        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull
                                        {
                                            // we are not blocked by this one
                                            if self.newKeys.contains(newuser.userKey) {}
                                            else
                                            {
                                                self.users.append(newuser)
                                                self.newKeys.append(newuser.userKey)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

In essence users can be at a certain place at a certain date. They put down the date they are going to be there, as explained in code below. that date may overlap with other users that are going to be in that area, in a period ranging of say 7 days before until 21 days after. those users can be followed, blocked. but I’m getting those to display in the tableView. If they put in a different date or place, a different set of users will pop up.

```
    if let userStartDate = beginningDate as? Double
    {
        let intUserStartDate = Int(userStartDate)

        dateRangeStart = intUserStartDate - 604800

        dateRangeEnd = intUserStartDate + 1814400

        print(dateRangeStart, intUserStartDate, dateRangeEnd)

        updateUsers()
    }
    else
    {
        updateUsersWithoutDate()
    }
```

Comment: The real issue with blocks inside blocks is timing. Your computer code is going to execute much faster than getting data from the Firebase server so you may have code executing before your data is returned. In this case the code will read in nodes that match a date range one at a time (.childAdded) and then any time a new child is added within that range. Can you describe what the intended result is and I am probably overlooking something, but what are you iterating over in:  for datesKey in snapshot.children - a series of timestamps?

Comment: Oh, and adding observers inside observers may not be the best idea. If you have an observer inside and observer, then if a change causes the inside observer to fire then that change would also cause the outside observer to fire. Probably better to structure your data in a way to keep the observers more specific to the data you are looking for to change. Perhaps another node that can be observed that keeps a reference to the data.

Comment: Hi, Jay. Edited the question above. What you are saying is that observers within observers are not a good idea, which i could feel, but I’m not sure how to query on different nodes and combine those results in a different way, You say I should set up different nodes, but with different variables set up by the users, that would result in a lot of nodes, wouldn’t it. have you got any suggestions? Much appreciated, btw.

Comment: Conceptually, are we just looking for intersections of specific locations and a range of times ( +/- 7 days for example) amongst your users?

Comment: that's exactly right, obviously only loading them in tableview if they are not blocked by the user and the user is not blocked by them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not be an answer or help at all but I want to throw it out there.

Given that you want to really look for two things: locations and times, we need some mechanics to handle it.

The locations are more static; i.e. the bowling ally will always be the bowling ally and the times are dynamic and we need a range. So, given a structure

```
{
  "events" : {
    "event_0" : {
      "loc_time" : "bowling_5"
    },
    "event_1" : {
      "loc_time" : "tennis_7"
    },
    "event_2" : {
      "loc_time" : "tennis_8"
    },
    "event_3" : {
      "loc_time" : "dinner_9"
    }
  }
}
```

This structure handles both criteria. You can easily query for all nodes that have location of tennis at a time of 7. You can also query the range for tennis from start time of 6 and end time of 9, which will return tennis_7 and tennis_8

Here's some ObjC code to do just that

```
Firebase *ref = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"events"];

FQuery *query = [[[ref queryOrderedByChild:@"loc_time"] 
                   queryStartingAtValue:@"tennis_6"] queryEndingAtValue:@"tennis_8"];

[query observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot);

}];
```

You can extrapolate from this substituting your locations for location and distance or timestamps for the time.

Another modification (and this may be obvious but stating it for clarity) is to use a reference to your locations instead of the actual name (bowling, tennis); i.e.

```
events
   "event_0" : {
      "loc_time" : "-JAY8jk12998f_20160311140200" // locationRef_timestamp
    },

locations
   -JAY8jk12998f : {
      "loc_name": "Fernando's Hideaway"
   }
```

Structuring your data in the way to want to get to it can significantly reduce your code (and the complexity of queries within queries etc).

Hope that helps.

Comment: It most certainly is an answer, a great one at that, as it makes me think differently about the structure of the data and the reduction of code. 
That said, a bowling alley is indeed a bowling alley, however I would be interested in users that not directly are interested in that particular bowling alley, but bowling in general, in my vicinity. Because there are not that many people bowling nowadays, I would also like to know about people looking to do some bowling in the other neighbourhoods in town or even the next village.
And seeing that I live in a cosmopolitan town,

Comment: where quite a few people have their phones set into a different language, I would really need to rely on the location data as opposed to the name bowling. For example ‘London” would be Londres’ in Spanish, meaning that I cannot search for say 
queryStartingAtValue:@"London_ 1457513382”] queryEndingAtValue:@"London_ 1458118182”
queryStartingAtValue:@"Londres_ 1457513382”] queryEndingAtValue:@"Londres_ 1458118182”,

Comment: As someone would miss out on bowling with me, as I would be excluded from the query. Which means I would need to include a geo query for that information. and therefore I would still end up with as far I see a query in a query, but most likely I’m missing something here.

Comment: So the language followup question is a separate question. However, let me give you something to chew on. Imagine a node -JWLasd9882 with children of; English: London and Spanish: Londres'. If they are spanish, you query for the spanish word for London within that node. That will give you the key, -JWLasd9882.  *That's* the key you use to reference your locations; JWLasd9882_1457513382. What you are doing here is disassociating variables (different spellings of city names for example) from the data and relying on references to point the way.

Comment: On the bowling alley: you could implement a child 'category' node or perhaps a 'recreational_activity' node where you could indicate that the establishment has some kind of recreational activity. Or, flipping that around, have a separate node that contains each city (or place) reference and then children to indicate what activities are available. It's not a problem to have a query within a query. However, you want to minimize the depth by structuring your data in a way that you get as much as possible. Also, don't be afraid to duplicate data with different structures -  disk space is cheap!

Comment: Bit late maybe, but restructured some of the data as suggested and seems to work a lot smoother. Many thanks.